# Troubles with integrating firebase in my app

Tags: android

So i am using the firebase assistant to integrate a "real-time database" into my app but i am having some troubles with the gradle files
here is my project gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'




        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And here is my module gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.matei.gotcha20"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2"
    compile 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'

}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error i am getting is the following:Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 11.6.2.
>   If i delete this line

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

it works but the firebase assisstant add that line automatically when i click on "integrate real-time database"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Firebase database dependency is 11.0.4 and auth is 11.6.2

Make both 11.6.2

Also use google services version 3.1.1 in your root level gradle file